# jQuery Keyup function works in Chrome and firefox, but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

First off, apologies for the poor title, but I honestly don't know enough about jQuery to be specific about what isn't working and other similarly-titled questions don't provide a working solution. HTML code is below. My addition ,subtraction working in Chrome and Firefox. But not in Internet Explorer.

```
<tr>
        <td width="125"><b>Receiving Quarantine </b></td>
        <td>
        <input type="textbox" name="rcv_quantity" class="tqty" id="totalAmt"  value="<?php echo $row->rcv_quantity; ?>" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;" readonly /> 
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="125"><b>Lot Released </b></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="lot_rel" id="lr1" class="lr" onblur="checkTextField(this);" />   
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="125"><b>Total Lot Released </b></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="total_lot_rel" id="tlrr" class="tlr" value="<?php echo $row->total_lot_rel; ?>" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;" readonly /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="sih" id="sih" class="sih" value="<?php echo $row->in_hand_nt_rel; ?>"  />   
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="125"><b>Rejected </b></td>
        <td>
        <input type="textbox" name="rejected" id="re" class="lrr"  value="<?php echo $row->rejected; ?> " /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I use this jQuery for calculation. And write this jQuery at the bottom of my HTML page.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.lr,#re').keyup(function () {
            $('.tqty, #totalAmt').val(<?php echo $row->rcv_quantity; ?>);
            $('.tlr,#tlrr').val(<?php echo $row->total_lot_rel; ?>);
            $('.sih,#sih').val(<?php echo $row->in_hand_nt_rel; ?>);
            // Loop through all inputs and re-calculate the total
            var total = parseFloat(totalAmt.value);
            var total_lr = parseFloat(tlrr.value);
            var total_sih = parseFloat(sih.value);
            $('.lr,#re').each(function () {
            // the "+" before the variable makes sure it's a number instead of a string
            // the "or 0" makes it 0 if it's empty, instead of "undefined"
            var number = +$(this).val() || 0;
            total -= +number; // adds up the numbers
            decimal = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2); 
            // sets the total to 2 decimal places
            });
            //----------------------------
            $('.lr').each(function () {

            var number = +$(this).val() || 0;
            total_lr += +number;
            total_sih += +number;

            decimal1 = parseFloat(total_lr).toFixed(2); 
            decimal2 = parseFloat(total_sih).toFixed(2);
            // sets the total to 2 decimal places
            });
            //--------------------------------
            // Update the total
            $('#totalAmt').val(decimal);
            $('#tlrr').val(decimal1);
            $('#sih').val(decimal2);

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two, and it pays you that time back immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, you should consider *using* it.

The problem is that what you've passed into `getElementsByClassName` isn't a class name, it's a class *selector*. You don't want that `.` there if you use that function. e.g.:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName('lr');
// No . here --------------------------------^
```

That makes it work if we fix various typos:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var cells = document.getElementsByClassName('lr');
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if ($(cells[i]).val() > 0)
      cells[i].disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Lot Released-1 </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lot_rel1" id="lr1" class="lr" value="400" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Lot Released-2 </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lot_rel2" id="lr2" class="lr" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Lot Released-3 </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lot_rel3" id="lr3" class="lr" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But again, if you're using jQuery, let's use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lr").each(function() {
    if (this.value > 0) {   // <=== Note! There's an implied type coercion here
      this.disabled = true
    }
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lr").each(function() {
    if (this.value > 0) {   // <=== Note! There's an implied type coercion here
      this.disabled = true
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Lot Released-1 </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lot_rel1" id="lr1" class="lr" value="400" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Lot Released-2 </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lot_rel2" id="lr2" class="lr" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Lot Released-3 </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lot_rel3" id="lr3" class="lr" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Additionally, it's `type="text"`, not `type="textbox"`. I've also made that change above.

Comment: You are right . I used these three textbox value in addition and subtraction . When one textbox is disabled it  involved further  addition and subtraction. But I don't want these I want when textbox is disabled it  won't interrupt any addition and subtraction. Please help me.

Comment: @MasudSarker: I answered the question you asked. I have no idea what question you're asking with that comment. Good luck.

Comment: Here is any keyword which disable textbox as this textbox value can't perform any jquery  addition and subtraction. Thanks for good communication.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(.lr).each(function(){
       if($(this).val() > 0)
           this.disabled = true;
    });
)};
```

Consider using this, because it seems like you are using jQuery, since you added $ in that if-statement.

Also, `document.getElementByClassName('.lr')` is not correct because of the `.` you added to it, since you already are looking for class names, you don't need to add `.`, or else you actually writing a selector and not a classname.

Comment: It works nice. Can you help me about this. Disabling a textbox if it has value and ignored this disabled value in addition and subtraction in jquery. There is any keyword like disable which will disable textbox also won't perform any jquery addition and subtraction?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). Try typing this into your developer console.

```
$("#lr1").prop("disabled", true);
```

You'll see that this properly disables it. So here would be your proper jQuery, including type checking and all of that goodness.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lr').each(function(){
        if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
            return;
        }
        if (parseFloat($(this).val()) > 0) {
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I was still playing around with the code when I hit tab and space bar, accidentally posting the incomplete answer. Now it just looks derivative .__.

Comment: Hmm I got it. Can you help me about this. Disabling a textbox if it has value and ignored this disabled value in addition and subtraction in jquery. There is any keyword like disable which will disable textbox also value won't count any jquery addition and subtraction?

Comment: Uhm, what? I honestly do not understand what you are asking. If you want to use arithmetic on text inputs, set variables equal to `parseFloat($(selector).val())` and use `isNaN` to avoid NaN propagation. You can then set the new value with `$(selector).val(newvalue)`. If you want to exclude disabled inputs from selectors, you can use `$(".lr:not([disabled])")`.

Comment: Did that answer your second question?